# How do I bring up my wireless network at boot?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, boot

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04. I have a wireless USB card. When I begin the boot process I see:

`Waiting for network configuration`

It turns out that the network never comes up. But once I get to the command line, if I type: `ifup wlan0`, then I have network access. My /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid xxxxxxx
wpa-psk xxxxxxxx
```

Looking in my network-interface-wlan0.log shows:

```
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: Read-only file system
Failed to bring up wlan0.
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: Read-only file system
ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured
```

I've looked at other askubuntu.com questions similar to this, but they don't seem to apply.

**How can I get my system to network wirelessly at boot?**

Additional information:

I did some poking around. Basically once I login I need to do a:

`ifdown wlan0`

because I think that ip thinks that is is up, but in /var/run/network the only thing that is 'up' is ifup.lo. Then I do a

'ifup -a'

and then everything works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: Read-only file system

According to your log you 'll need to use wpa_supplicant.

So add something similar to this:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Contents of /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf :

```
network={
        ssid="ADD-YOUR-SSID-HERE"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
        psk="ADD-YOUR-WPA-PASSWORD-HERE"
}
```

Comment: What do we add it to?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ifup wlan0` to your `/etc/rc.local` file. Add the command `ifup wlan0` *before* the `exit 0`. Also add the command `ifdown wlan0` before the `ifup wlan0` like so:

```
...
ifdown wlan0
ifup wlan0

exit 0
```

For some reason when Ubuntu starts, it thinks that wlan0 is up. So you have to shut it down and have it back up again.

Comment: This didn't work. I don't think this is happening because ifup isn't be called. I think there's something else wonky going on with the networking system.

Comment: Hi, ifup wlan0 should be above the 'exit 0' line. Thanks @Piyush Kumar for mentioning

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to **WPA-PSK and WPA2-PSK (Aka "WPA Personal" and "WPA2 Personal" respectively)**

- Run:

  ```
  $ wpa_passphrase myssid my_very_secret_passphrase
  ```

Copy the value of "psk=" from the output above.

- Open /etc/network/interfaces in a text editor :

  ```
  $ sudo sensible-editor /etc/network/interfaces
  ```
- Define appropriate stanzas for your wireless interface, along with
  the SSID and PSK HASH. For example :

  ```
  auto wlan0
  face wlan0 inet dhcp
     wpa-ssid <myssid>
     wpa-psk <ccb290fd4fe6b22935cbae3144..>
  ```
- Finally run:

  ```
  $ sudo ifup wlan0
  ```

**Note:**
*Some answers seems to suggest configuring a separate `wpa_supplicant.conf`. But it is only required for WPA-EAP, EAP-TLS networks.*

**How can I get my system to network wirelessly at boot?**

The `auto` stanza does bring up the interface at system startup.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter such a problem.

I noticed that someone said, delete the text about primary network interface, with first 2 lines remaining.

It works, but no network is connected.

Then I write the text of primary network interface back into the interfaces file and reboot.

It's surprising to find not only no hints "**waiting for network configuration**" occur, but I could connect to the internet.

I don't know whether it is useful for any others.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the filesystem is read-only at boot. At this point only static settings work because udev raises network hotplug signal before the filesystem is ready.

The solution is to change the `/etc/init/network-interface.conf` file in this line:

```
"ifup --allow auto ..." to
"ifup --allow=hotplug ...".
```

You will have to mark you hotplug PCMCI and USB network adapters as "hotplug" in `/etc/network/interfaces` for them to continue to work, and you should plug them in after boot, not before.